# What do you use as a portable lighting mono pole?

Tags: lighting, strobes, lightstands, on-location

Does anyone of you have an elegant solution or product in mind to use as a handheld mono pole for on-location use with a spigot for attaching a strobe head with a soft box?

Let's say a Godox AD600 with detached head to keep the weight down and a 90cm octabox (just to have some idea of the weight involved).

I could use a broom stick and a manfrotto super clamp, but maybe there are better solutions. Especially for the person holding the thing.

Comment: What is the weight/mass of the light and modifier? There's a significant difference between a small speedlite with a small, portable softbox and a studio monolight with a large studio style softbox.

Comment: A broom stick is not elegant... or safe. You do not want your photoshoot ruined by dropint a light on the head of anyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A light stand?

As an assistant I have used a light stand with it's legs collapsed in order to hold a strobe with a soft box attached   over a location that was difficult to set fixed stands in place. It has the necessary stud/spigot  for a strobe built on to it. In fact having the legs on it but collapsed help to keep the pole from rotating due to the weight (*gravity*) of the soft box, they help to aim the soft box for directing the light to where it is needed.

A boom pole off of a [studio light boom](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/272945-REG/Impact_3218_Multiboom_Light_Stand_Reflector_Holder.html).

A Monopod with [stud adapter](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1305583-REG/impact_srp_101p_round_short_adapter_with.html) screwed onto the head.

If you are on a budget you can look for used monopods or equipment and get the proper stud/adapter from a photo equip supplier. Maybe an old light stand and remove the legs for a dedicated boom. (*I say leave the legs on for control*)

Comment: A light stand is by far the best option. When the assistant is tired or needs to do someting else the light can just... stand.

Comment: And some are really cheap, and decent quality.